# Apply Functions to get to Multiple States in Matlab

Tags: matlab, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation

I am trying to create a program that converts between multiple coordinate systems in Matlab.

I have different systems and want to transfer between them. There are different topocentric, geocentric & heliocentric systems. I have written the transformation matrices to transfer between these coordinate systems.

To simplify this problem I'll use an example.

If I have 3 coordinate systems:

Cartesian , Cylindrical & Spherical Coordinates

To convert from Cylindrical coordinates to Cartesian coordinates. I can apply:

```
x = r ∙ cos(ø)
y = r ∙ sin(ø)
z = z
```

To convert from Spherical coordinates to Cartesian coordinates. I can apply:

```
x = R ∙ sin(θ) ∙ cos(ø)
y = R ∙ sin(θ) ∙ sin(ø)
z = R ∙ cos(θ)
```

Assuming we don't convert Spherical Coordinates directly to Cylindrical Coordinates, we convert:

- Spherical -> Cartesian
- Cartesian -> Cylindrical

In my real problem, I have 8 different coordinate systems with transformations back and forth between each of them. The systems have only have two paths linking to different coordinate systems.

It looks like this:

A <-> B <-> C <-> D <-> E <-> F <-> G <-> H

I want to create a method for the user to choose a coordinate system, input coordinates and select the destination coordinate systems.

Instead of manually writing functions for: A -> C , A -> D , A -> E ... for 54 different steps

Is there a way I can create a system to connect the paths?
Is there a way I can use a graph or nodes and apply functions which connect the nodes (A->C)
What is this concept so I can read up more on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement something complicated with object oriented programming, but to keep things simple I propose to store all different types of coordinates as structs that all have a member `type` and whatever other members needed for that particular type of coordinate.

You could then define all your conversion functions that do a single step to all have the same function signature `function out_coord = A2B(in_coord)`, e.g.:

```
function cart = sphere2cart(sphere)
assert(strcmp(sphere.type, 'sphere')) % make sure input is correct type
cart.type = 'cart';
cart.x = sphere.R * sin(sphere.theta) * cos(sphere.omega);
cart.y = sphere.R * sin(sphere.theta) * sin(sphere.omega);
cart.z = sphere.R * cos(sphere.theta);
```

These functions can be called from one universal `convert` function like this:

```
function output_coord = convert(input_coord, target_type)
output_coord = input_coord;
while ~strcmp(output_coord.type, target_type)
    func = get_next_conversion_func(input_coord.type, target_type);
    output_coord = func(output_coord);
end
```

which does one conversion step at a time, until `output_coord` has the correct type. The only missing step is then a function that determines which conversion to do next, based on the current type and the target type. In your case with a 'linear' conversion chain, this is not so hard. In more complex cases, where the types are connected in a complex graph, this might require some shortest path algorithm. Unfortunately, this is a bit cumbersome to implement in Matlab, but one hard-coded solution might be something like:

```
function func = get_next_conversion_func(current_type. target_type);
switch current_type
    case 'A'
        func = @A2B;
    case 'B'
        switch target_type
            case 'A'
                func = @B2A;
            case {'C','D','E'}
                func = @B2C;
        end
    case 'C'
        switch target_type
            case {'A','B'}
                func = @C2B;
            case {'D','E'}
                func = @C2D;
        end
    ...
end
```

For sure, there are smarter ways to implement this, this is basically a dispatch table that says in which direction to go based on the current type and the target type.

**EDIT**

Following Jonas' suggestion of doing all conversions via one central type (let's say `C`), all of this can be simplified to

```
function output_coord = convert(input_coord, target_type)
output_coord = input_coord;
if strcmp(output_coord.type, target_type)
    return % nothing to convert
end

if ~strcmp(output_coord.type, 'C')
    switch output_coord.type
        case 'A'
            output_coord = A2C(output_coord)
        case 'B'
            output_coord = B2C(output_coord)
        case 'D'
            output_coord = D2C(output_coord)
        case 'E'
            output_coord = E2C(output_coord)
    end
end

assert(strcmp(output_coord.type, 'C'))

if ~strcmp(output_coord.type, target_type)
    switch target_type
        case 'A'
            output_coord = C2A(output_coord)
        case 'B'
            output_coord = C2B(output_coord)
        case 'D'
            output_coord = C2D(output_coord)
        case 'E'
            output_coord = C2E(output_coord)
    end
end
```

Comment: you may want to use input_coord in your first switch/case block

Comment: I do a `output_coord = intput_coord` first, but this can for sure be cleaned up a bit. Code is untested ...

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted!

I like the original solution you gave and think that is what I am looking for.
But with @Jonas's suggestion this allows for less functions to define explicitly and makes it even better.

Thanks guys!


I prefer to code in Java and Python so I'd love to learn more about this problem. I looked into dispatch tables and it might be what I was looking for. Wondering if that is the correct term so I can read up on it for myself?

Comment: The term to search for is probably 'dispatch table' or 'single dispatch'. And yes, this would be much easier in Python than in Matlab (have a look at numpy, if you didn't yet). Note that Jonas' solution does not reduce the number of functions, it just makes the logic easier and requires 2 conversions at most. Both in case of a linear chain and Jonas' star scheme, you will need `2 * (n-1)` conversion functions. Please accept the answer if you are happy.

Answer (score 2):

In your current logic, `A <-> B <-> C <-> D <-> E <-> F <-> G <-> H`, you will have to write 14 functions for converting (if `A->B` and `B->A` count as two).

I suggest that instead, you choose one reference coordinate system, say, A and write the functions `A<->B`, `A<->C`, etc.

This solution requires you to write the same number of functions as your solution, but the logic becomes trivial. Furthermore, each conversion takes a maximum of two conversion steps, which will avoid accumulating round-off errors when you perform a chain of conversions.

Comment: 'a maximum of one' -> 'a maximum of two' ?

Comment: The suggestion to do all conversions via one reference type is a good one. The actual implementation would still look similar to my answer.

Comment: I like this solution and I didn't think of this before.

To make sure I understand. If I want to transform `C->E`, I input the coordinates in input system C, convert `C->A`, then `A->E`.

On a deeper look, This requires 54 functions such as `B->D` , `B->E`...

I would still have to write the functions:

`function [output_coord] = coordC_to_coordE(input_coord)`
`output_coord = coordA_to_coordE(coordC_to_coordA(input_coord))`

I want to use a graph or some programming concept to avoid defining 54 functions to jump between the coordinate systems.
Thanks for the help and I appreciate the idea :)